# how to Redirect to login page when session expires asp.net MVC 5 ASP.net Identity 2.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I have created default webproject in VS2013 with latest ASP.net Identity 2.0. I would like to know what setting are reuired to change the timeout of logging session so that I can test pratically.

Answer (score 0):

You can overrride this in Startup.Auth.cs

```
        // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
        // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
        // Configure the sign in cookie
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            },

            //*** This will override the default **** 
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)

        });
```